# Function call behavior

Tags: javascript

In my test the `mylog` function is called three times, but looking at source I suppose it should be executed only twice.

```
<html>
<div id='log'></div>
<script>

var Foo = { counter : "inside the Foo object" };
var counter = "Global";

Foo.method = function() {
    var counter = "inside Foo.method";
    mylog("counter = "+this.counter);
    function test() {
        // this is set to the global object
        mylog("counter = "+this.counter);
    }
    test();
}

Foo.method();

function mylog(msg) {
    log = document.getElementById("log");
    log.innerHTML += log.innerHTML + msg + "<br />";
}
</script>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8BBF7/

This is the output:

```
counter = inside the Foo object
counter = inside the Foo object
counter = Global
```

As told I expected `mylog` function is called only twice. Can someone explain me why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the `+=` to an `=` on the line `log.innerHTML += log.innerHTML + msg + "<br />";` or keep it and use the form `log.innerHTML += msg + "<br />";`

Answer (score 2):

That's because of this

```
log.innerHTML += log.innerHTML + msg + "<br />";
```

You add the current innerHTML as well, so you duplicate earlier logs. Do it like this

```
log.innerHTML += msg + "<br />";
```

or

```
log.innerHTML = log.innerHTML + msg + "<br />";
```

Answer (score 2):

The function is called 2 times, but you made a mistake on appending log.InnerHTML . You append log.innerHTML 2 times

Working code:

```
function mylog(msg) {
    log = document.getElementById("log");
    log.innerHTML +=  msg + "<br />";
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/8BBF7/16/

Answer (score 1):

It's only called twice. Check your `mylog()`:

```
function mylog(msg) {
    log = document.getElementById("log");
    log.innerHTML += log.innerHTML + msg + "<br />";
}
```

Either use

```
log.innerHTML = log.innerHTML + msg + "<br />";
```

or

```
log.innerHTML += msg + "<br />";
```